# JavaFx: parent.lookup returns null

Tags: java, javafx

I use osgi+cdi and I have the following code:

```
Parent parent=null;
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader=getFxmlLoader();
try {
    parent = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load(getFxmlStream("tasklist.fxml"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TestGoView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
ComboBox comboBox=(ComboBox) parent.lookup("#testComboBox");
if (comboBox==null){
    System.out.println("COMBOBOX NULL");
}else{
    System.out.println("COMBOBOX NOT NULL");
}
```

And I have the following tasklist.fxml

```
<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="757.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.techsenger.testgo.core.adm.task.list.TaskDirListController">
   <children>
      <HBox>
         <children>
            <ToolBar maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" HBox.hgrow="SOMETIMES">
               <items>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="testComboBox" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" />
               </items>
            </ToolBar>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

However parent.lookup("#testComboBox") returns null. How to explain it? I've checked the name of ID several times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a lookup, which will only work after the scene has been rendered, you can put the logic you need in your [controller class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers). You can inject elements from the FXML file into the controller class by annotating them `@FXML`.

```
public class TaskDirListController {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<...> testComboBox ;

    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println(testComboBox);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Lookups are generally not robust, and I would recommend avoiding using them. If you really need to access something defined in the FXML file from a class other than the controller, the first thing to do is to consider reorganizing things so that you don't need to do this: it really indicates that your overall design is wrong.

If you really need this for some reason, it's better to use the `FXMLLoader`'s `namespace` than a lookup:

```
Parent parent=null;
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader=getFxmlLoader();
try {
    parent = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load(getFxmlStream("tasklist.fxml"));
    ComboBox<?> comboBox = (ComboBox<?>) fxmlLoader.getNamespace().get("testComboBox");
    System.out.println(comboBox);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TestGoView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: I have View which is better to name ViewBuilder. The code I provided is from this View. At this class I put all logic - create columns, configuring comboboxes etc. That's why I need this combobox. Do you think it's bad idea to put all building view logic at separate class. Do you mean it's better to leave such logic in controller?

Comment: I would put it in the controller. You might also consider using [this pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components)

Answer (score 6):

It is because you are trying to use lookup before showing the parent on the screen.

```java
Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("tasklist.fxml"));

System.out.println(root.lookup("#testComboBox")); //returns  null
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
primaryStage.show();
System.out.println(root.lookup("#testComboBox")); //returns 
// ComboBox[id=testComboBox, styleClass=combo-box-base combo-box]
```