# How can I get button text by knowing its id in javafx

Tags: java, button, javafx

So i am a beginner programmer and
what I'm trying to do is to get specific button's text by knowing its `fx:id`
Is it possible?
For example if button `fx:id = "buttonOne"` and `text = "X"`
how can I get `X`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your button in controller (`fx:id` should be equals name of the field):

```
@FXML
Button buttonOne;
```

And just use `getText()`:

```
buttonOne.getText();
```

Comment: It's a good solution but the thing is I'll have to create nine buttons just for checking text so I wondered if its possible to compare two different button texts without creating a new object

Comment: @DudDerYDuDe yes, you can get element by id. Try this: String text = ((Button) scene.lookup("#buttonOne")).getText();

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.Thanks for help

Comment: I would not recommend the answer in the comment. See Jame D's comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685672/javafx-parent-lookup-returns-null). If you don't want to take the time to do as this answer suggests, you should try to put all the buttons into a parent element and retrieve them as children. Then you can loop through them looking for the id and return the Button with that id.